# how to get video file duration in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video, duration

I wants to get video file duration in C#. I have the to get video file duration but code works only local computer. If i deploy my  code on server and upload a video file then this code gives error. I m using the following code to get video time.

using QuartzTypeLib;

```
 string file1 = "c://ds.mpeg"
        IMediaPosition m_objMediaPosition = null;
        FilgraphManager m_objFilterGraph = new FilgraphManager();
        m_objFilterGraph.RenderFile(filename);
        m_objMediaPosition = m_objFilterGraph as IMediaPosition;

        int s = (int)m_objMediaPosition.Duration;
        int h = s / 3600;
        int m = (s - (h * 3600)) / 60;
        s = s - (h * 3600 + m * 60);

        string time = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", h, m, s);
        lblmsg.Text = time.ToString();
        m_objMediaPosition = null;
        m_objFilterGraph = null;
```

Have u any code which return time duration of a uploaded video file.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty way with ffmpeg: run ffmpeg -i "c:\ds.mpeg" and parse the output.

Comment: Remember that the ffmpeg text output goes to stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 2):

try using DirectShowLib

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the control you are using is trying to reference the graphics hardware in some way to perform this function. i.e. using the UI to be able to enumerate this information.

Perhaps you can look at the [MediaElement control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the video length in a bit different way :
Actually using Windows Media Player Component also, we can get the duration of the video.
Following code snippet may help you guys :

```
using WMPLib;
// ...your code here...

var player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
var clip = player.newMedia(filePath);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clip.duration));
```

> and don't forget to add the reference of **`wmp.dll`** which will be
>   present in **`System32`** folder.